# QML Icons bad quality

Tags: qml, icons, pyside2

I want to use buttons with icons in my QML/PySide2 app. But unfortunately QML dramatically reduces quality of icon. Here is printscreen of the same icon - on the left is opened in standard windows photo viewer and on the right in QML app. Icon is in size 96x96, .png format and in qml code I set the icon width and height as 96. What could cause this? Are there some setting "underhood" that reduce resolution of the icon?

[image]

Comment: Is the image positioned on a non-integer boundary? Qt will use anti-aliasing to approximate sub-pixel drawing.

Comment: read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-icons.html#icon-themes

Comment: @JarMan Thanks!!! :D The problem was in non-integer boundary - GridLayout margins were fraction from parent dimensions.

Comment: @eyllanesc Could you provide some PySide2 example? I've read earlier this page, but I don't have .qrc file in my project and my C++ knowledge equals to 0 so I gave up :/ I will be very gratefull, because this should be useful in the future :D